# Updating table by appending onto it several hundred rows

Tags: mysql, sql

So the task I have in mind would be simple if it were only a few rows that needed to be added, but what I need to add is several hundred rows, that I have in the form of a `CSV` file.

Basically what happened at work is someone turned off a service that fed our db some data. So I need to manually update the db with data from this period that was missing.

My plan is to:

- Upload the csv file as another table
- Somehow use a merge that appends the rows.

My issues are that:

- The ordering of the columns in both tables is different. They have exactly the same columns, but the order of them is different.
- Also, the sql table has 1 extra column not present in the table from the csv file.

I'm curious as to how I should go about attempting a "vertical" merge of rows, when the order of columns is different, and when I have 1 less column than the original table. Column names are otherwise identical.

Comment: Do you know SQL at all? I'm asking, because the order of columns in the table definition is meaningless. You always name the columns, so it never matters what order they have in the table definition.

Comment: You talk about *merge*, and you talk about *append*. Which is it? *Append* simply means inserting new rows at the end, which is hardly difficult. Merge implies that some rows already exist, as identified by the values of one or more columns, and that existing rows should be updated, and doing so may require more work. As for the extra column, how can we answer anything about that, when we have no clue what that column is, what is means?

Comment: Hey Andreas - you're right, I meant append. Because all I'm doing is adding new rows.

The missing column is meaningless because I'm fine with it having blank values in the new rows that get inserted.

Comment: Then I don't see the problem. What *specific* problem do you have? Use an [INSERT from SELECT](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+insert+from+select) statement.

Comment: Thanks! my issue was that I had only ever updated rows individually, and used the method that involves sequentially writing out the column names. I was wondering if there was a way to just upload a csv into mysql, and then automatically append all its rows into another table based on common columns.

Comment: I see nothing in the question asking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python pandas to append the values to your mysql table.

1. Import libraries

   ```
        import pandas as pd
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        import sqlalchemy
   ```
2. Create engine and function to dump your data.

   ```
      engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("%s://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (
      "mysql+pymysql",
      "username",
      "password",
      "ip",
       port,
      "mysql database name"
       ))

    def dump_to_sql(dump_df, relationship):

          '''
          Uses pandas.to_sql to dump directly into the DB
         '''

         global engine
         dump_df.to_sql(name=relationship, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False,chunksize=1000)
   ```
3. Read your csv as a pandas dataframe and pass it to the function.

   ```
       df=pd.read_csv('name_of_your_csv.csv')
       dump_to_sql(df,'name of your mysql table in which you want to upload')
   ```

Note:Make sure your csv has the same column names as your mysql table.Missing columns will be filled with null values.